# three.js, dat.GUI slider controlled by code, morph targets do not move

Tags: opencv, three.js, dat.gui

I work on a human face that the mouth should move about external coordinates (OpenCV and dlibs). In a first step I try to control the dat.GUI by code, which already works. But now I have the problem that the morph targets do not move when I control by code. The sliders move, but the face doesn't. When I use the mouse, they work perfectly. I ask for help with this problem.

```js
<script>  
  
 // Laden der 3DScene
 var scene = new THREE.Scene();

 // Laden der Kamear Perspektive
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 17;
  camera.position.y = 3;

 // Laden des Renderers
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: false });
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000 );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  
 // Laden des Orbitcontrollers
 var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

 // Laden der Lichter (Beleuchtung)
 var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

 var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFDD );
    light.position.set( -15, 10, 15 );
    scene.add(light);

 // Laden des Json Modells 
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();     
  loader.load( "./three/models/JSON/test/mkh_shapes.json", function (geometry) { 
 var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({morphTargets: true});
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);    
    mesh.scale.set(1.2,1.2,1.2);        //Modellgrösse die angezeigt wird      
    mesh.position.x = 0;    //Position (x = nach rechts+ links-)  
    mesh.position.y = -19;    //Position (y = nach oben +, unten-)
    mesh.position.z = 0;    //Position (z = nach vorne +, hinten-)
 
    scene.add(mesh);
 
 //dat.Gui 
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
     
   
 var shape = {        
    mouth_open: 0.0,  //Anfangsposition 0.0                  
 };
        
 var gui = new dat.GUI();
 var folder = gui.addFolder( 'Morph Targets' );   
   folder.add( shape, 'mouth_open', 0, 1 ).step( 0.01 ).name('mouth_open').listen().onChange ( function( a ) {       mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 40 ] = a;} );
   folder.open();
   
 var updateGui = function() {
  for (var i in folder.__controllers) {
   folder.__controllers[i].updateDisplay();
  }
 }
  
 var time = Date.now() * 0.003;                                 
  shape.mouth_open = 0.50 //* Math.sin( 0.5 * time ) + 0.3;   
   
  //scene.add(shape);
  
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}); 
 
function animate() {
  render();
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function render() {  
  renderer.clear();
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
 
animate();
 
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I have made my own version with extra features like :

- Gui auto resize based on content div.
- Improved slidecontroller as unique controller (slide or number insert);
- Multi language automatic support
- Auto check for conflicts in options, then ask for confirm or cancel.
- Auto Show/hide other controllers when option selected deselected (example show color list only if "custom color is selected")
  ecc.. ecc..

here is the [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh_DpKYTifA&vq=large)

Now is more confortable and easy to use.